# Date Picker; Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0

Tags: swift

We know that this is asked a lot already on this webpage, but we can't seem to find the answer to our problem.

We're trying to create a Money Management app for a school project. We've created a tableview to which the user should be able to add their spendings with, name, price, date and a catagorie. We would like to make it possible that if the user clicks the textfield for the date, a datepicker showes up. That's the first part of our problem. If we click the textfield at the moment, a regular keyboard shows up. If we type anything random for the date and try to save it this error shows up:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0

We've tried anything and don't know what to do anymore. If someone is willing to help us, that would be amazing!

Thanks in advance!

Here is our code of the spending view controller:

```
import os.log

import UIKit

class SpendingViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var kledingImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var etenImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var thuisImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cadeausImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var voormijIMageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var uitjesImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var vervoerImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var overigImageView: UIImageView!


    /*
     This value is either passed by `SpendingTableViewController` in `prepare(for:sender:)`
     or constructed as part of adding a new spending.
     */

    var spending: Spending?
    var datePicker: UIDatePicker?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        dateTextField.tag = 1
        nameTextField.tag = 2
        amountTextField.tag = 2

        // Handle the text field's user input through delegate callbacks
        nameTextField.delegate = self
        amountTextField.delegate = self
        dateTextField.delegate = self

        if let spending = spending {
            nameTextField.text = spending.name
            amountTextField.text = String(spending.amount)
            photoImageView.image = spending.photo
            dateTextField.text = String(describing: spending.date)
        }

        // Enable the Save button only if the text field has a valid Meal name.
        updateSaveButtonState()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: TextField Delegate

    func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .full
        dateTextField.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)

        print("Try this at home")
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if textField.tag == 1 {
            datePicker? = UIDatePicker()
            textField.inputView = datePicker
            datePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

            print("This Worked")
        }

        // Disable the Save button while editing.
        saveButton.isEnabled = false

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        dateTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        updateSaveButtonState()
    }

    // MARK: Helper Methods
    func closekeyboard() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    // MARK: Touch Events
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        closekeyboard()
    }



    //MARK: Navigation



    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        // Depending on style of presentation (modal or push presentation), this view controller needs to be dismissed in two different ways.
        let isPresentingInAddSpendingMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController

        if isPresentingInAddSpendingMode {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else if let owningNavigationController = navigationController{
            owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
        }

        else {
            fatalError("The SpendingViewController is not inside a navigation controller.")
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    // This method lets you configure a view controller before it's presented.
    override func prepare(for: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let sender = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, saveButton === sender {
            let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
            let photo = photoImageView.image
            let amount = Double(amountTextField.text!) ?? 0
            let date = datePicker?.date

            // Set the balance to be passed to BalanceTableViewController after the unwind segue.
            spending = Spending(name: name, photo: photo, amount: amount, date: date!)
        }
    }

    // MARK: Actions


    @IBAction func setphotoImageViewtoKleding(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Set chosen  photoImageView to category image.
        photoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Kleding_Kleur")

        // Set chosen categoryImageView to checked image.
        kledingImageView.image = UIImage(named:"KledingCheck_Kleur")

        // Set other categoryImageViews to unchecked image.
        etenImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Eten_Kleur")
        thuisImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Thuis_Kleur")
        cadeausImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Cadeaus_Kleur")
        voormijIMageView.image = UIImage(named: "Voormij_Kleur")
        uitjesImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Uitjes_Kleur")
        vervoerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Vervoer_Kleur")
        overigImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Overig_Kleur")
    }

    @IBAction func setphotoImageViewtoEten(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Set chosen  photoImageView to category image.
        photoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Eten_Kleur")

        // Set chosen categoryImageView to checked image.
        etenImageView.image = UIImage(named:"EtenCheck_Kleur")

        // Set other categoryImageViews to unchecked image.
        kledingImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Kleding_Kleur")
        thuisImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Thuis_Kleur")
        cadeausImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Cadeaus_Kleur")
        voormijIMageView.image = UIImage(named: "Voormij_Kleur")
        uitjesImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Uitjes_Kleur")
        vervoerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Vervoer_Kleur")
        overigImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Overig_Kleur")
    }

    @IBAction func setphotoImageViewtoThuis(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Set chosen  photoImageView to category image.
        photoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Thuis_Kleur")

        // Set chosen categoryImageView to checked image.
        thuisImageView.image = UIImage(named:"ThuisCheck_Kleur")

        // Set other categoryImageViews to unchecked image.
        etenImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Eten_Kleur")
        kledingImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Kleding_Kleur")
        cadeausImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Cadeaus_Kleur")
        voormijIMageView.image = UIImage(named: "Voormij_Kleur")
        uitjesImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Uitjes_Kleur")
        vervoerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Vervoer_Kleur")
        overigImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Overig_Kleur")
    }

    @IBAction func setphotoImageViewtoCadeaus(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Set chosen  photoImageView to category image.
        photoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Cadeaus_Kleur")

        // Set chosen categoryImageView to checked image.
        cadeausImageView.image = UIImage(named:"CadeausCheck_Kleur")

        // Set other categoryImageViews to unchecked image.
        etenImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Eten_Kleur")
        thuisImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Thuis_Kleur")
        kledingImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Kleding_Kleur")
        voormijIMageView.image = UIImage(named: "Voormij_Kleur")
        uitjesImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Uitjes_Kleur")
        vervoerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Vervoer_Kleur")
        overigImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Overig_Kleur")
    }

    @IBAction func setphotoImageViewtoVoormij(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Set chosen  photoImageView to category image.
        photoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Voormij_Kleur")

        // Set chosen categoryImageView to checked image.
        voormijIMageView.image = UIImage(named:"VoormijCheck_Kleur")

        // Set other categoryImageViews to unchecked image.
        etenImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Eten_Kleur")
        thuisImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Thuis_Kleur")
        cadeausImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Cadeaus_Kleur")
        kledingImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Kleding_Kleur")
        uitjesImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Uitjes_Kleur")
        vervoerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Vervoer_Kleur")
        overigImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Overig_Kleur")
    }

    @IBAction func setphotoImageViewtoUitjes(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Set chosen  photoImageView to category image.
        photoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Uitjes_Kleur")

        // Set chosen categoryImageView to checked image.
        uitjesImageView.image = UIImage(named:"UitjesCheck_Kleur")

        // Set other categoryImageViews to unchecked image.
        etenImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Eten_Kleur")
        thuisImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Thuis_Kleur")
        cadeausImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Cadeaus_Kleur")
        voormijIMageView.image = UIImage(named: "Voormij_Kleur")
        kledingImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Kleding_Kleur")
        vervoerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Vervoer_Kleur")
        overigImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Overig_Kleur")
    }

    @IBAction func setphotoImageViewtoVervoer(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Set chosen  photoImageView to category image.
        photoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Vervoer_Kleur")

        // Set chosen categoryImageView to checked image.
        vervoerImageView.image = UIImage(named:"VervoerCheck_Kleur")

        // Set other categoryImageViews to unchecked image.
        etenImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Eten_Kleur")
        thuisImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Thuis_Kleur")
        cadeausImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Cadeaus_Kleur")
        voormijIMageView.image = UIImage(named: "Voormij_Kleur")
        uitjesImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Uitjes_Kleur")
        kledingImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Kleding_Kleur")
        overigImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Overig_Kleur")
    }

    @IBAction func setphotoImageViewtoOverig(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Set chosen  photoImageView to category image.
        photoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Overig_Kleur")

        // Set chosen categoryImageView to checked image.
        overigImageView.image = UIImage(named:"OverigCheck_Kleur")

        // Set other categoryImageViews to unchecked image.
        etenImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Eten_Kleur")
        thuisImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Thuis_Kleur")
        cadeausImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Cadeaus_Kleur")
        voormijIMageView.image = UIImage(named: "Voormij_Kleur")
        uitjesImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Uitjes_Kleur")
        vervoerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Vervoer_Kleur")
        kledingImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Kleding_Kleur")
    }




    //MARK: Private Methods

    private func updateSaveButtonState() {
        // Disable the Save button if the text field is empty.
        let text = nameTextField.text ?? ""
        saveButton.isEnabled = !text.isEmpty

        let amount = Double(amountTextField.text!) ?? 0
        saveButton.isEnabled = !amount.isZero

    }

}
```

And this is the code of spending.swift:

```
import UIKit

import os.log

class Spending: NSObject, NSCoding {

    //MARK: Properties

    var name: String
    var photo: UIImage?
    var amount: Double
    var date: Date

    //MARK: Archiving Paths

    static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("spendings")

    //MARK: Types

    struct PropertyKey {
        static let name = "name"
        static let photo = "photo"
        static let amount = "amount"
        static let date = "date"
    }

    //MARK: Initialization

    init?(name: String, photo: UIImage?, amount: Double, date: Date) {

        // Initialization should fail if there is no name or if the rating is negative.
        if name.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }

        // Initialize stored properties.
        self.name = name
        self.photo = photo
        self.amount = amount
        self.date = date
    }

    //MARK: NSCoding

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: PropertyKey.name)
        aCoder.encode(photo, forKey: PropertyKey.photo)
        aCoder.encode(amount, forKey: PropertyKey.amount)
        aCoder.encode(date, forKey: PropertyKey.date)
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name) as! String
        let date = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.date) as! Date

        // Because photo is an optional property of Meal, just use conditional cast.
        let photo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.photo) as? UIImage
        let amount = aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: PropertyKey.amount)


        // Must call designated initializer.
        self.init(name: name, photo: photo, amount: amount, date: date)
    }


}
```

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGfHS.png)

Thanks!

**Output:**

```
  total: 20000.0
  total: 90.0
  2017-01-17 20:24:26.366841 MoneyManagement[94386:3693218] Adding a new spending.
  2017-01-17 20:24:28.092116 MoneyManagement[94386:3693218] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/emmadriesse/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/406EDDF1-C4A8-4139-8693-D727D43006AF/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
  2017-01-17 20:24:28.093887 MoneyManagement[94386:3693218] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
  2017-01-17 20:24:30.607 MoneyManagement[94386:3693218] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 1316927560_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
```

This Worked
fatal error: **unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)**

Comment: Is there any output in the console when the app crashes?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the output. I will put it in ghe message above.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line where it stops.  Examine all the things that you're passing to  the `Spending` constructor.  (`date` is probably nil.)  in general, test whether things can be unwrapped rather than using `!`.

Comment: Thanks Philip Mills, that worked!